# Confused about BP Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Recently I'm learning BP Neural Network for my English letter recognition. I implement a simple edition and find somthing confusing.

My simple edition is to recognize whether the input binary image is a `u`.

I have a binary image of a letter and extract the feature vector of that image by counting the foreground pixels of every `3x3` block. For example, for a `24x24` image, the size of feature vector is `64`.

Output `1` for `is a u` and `0` for `isn't a u`.

Then there's what I'm confused about:

First I input a `u` for training. and input `u`, `c`, `p`, `b`, `d` one by one to test. I get 5 `1`s.
Then I input `u`, `c`, `p`, `b`, `d` one by one for training, and input `u`, `c`, `p`, `b`, `d` one by one to test. I get 5 `0`s

Is it that the result of new training changes the result of old training makes the recognition fail?

Comment: It sounds like you need to train more, and on different examples. Perhaps with a lower learning rate. With a large enough learning rate, each example will sway the weights towards that answer. Additionally, you should try to balance the number of positive and negative examples.

Comment: So you presented each element of the input set only once?

Comment: Well, I think I have made a mistake at training stage. I need to train the set of sample iteratively.